# Access all items under specific div in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Hi i want to access all images under some specific div in javascript.My code is :

```
<div id="image-container" style="background-image:url(loading.gif)">
        <div class="fade-box" id="image-1"><a href="javascript:GoNext();"><img src="2bscene-logo.gif" alt="" width="330" height="108" border="0" /></a></div>
        <div class="fade-box" id="image-2" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript:GoNext();"><img src="streetgallery-logo.gif" alt="" width="330" height="108" border="0" /></a></div>
        <div class="fade-box" id="image-3" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript:GoNext();"><img src="g4m-logo.gif" alt="" width="330" height="108" border="0" /></a></div>
</div>
```

While my js code is :

```
var image_slide = new Array('image-1', 'image-2', 'image-3');
```

I want to get all `DIV`s based on `id` dynamically, not having a predefined array. How can I do that?

Comment: You've used the `prototype` tag. Did you mean `Prototype` (the library)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JavaScript, you can do this easily with the DOM:

```
var container = document.getElementById("image-container");
var child;
var image_slide = [];
for (child = container.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
    if (child.id && child.nodeName === "DIV") {
        image_slide.push(child.id);
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ugokaj/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ugokaj/1/edit)

Note that the code above must be run *after* the elements are already in the DOM. The best way to ensure that is to put the `script` tag below them in the page (just before the closing `</body>` element is good).

Comment: Thanks for your response .your code give me the error container is null .any idea why.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman: Provided this code is run *after* the markup you've posted is on the page, that shouldn't happen, as you clearly do have an element with that `id`. See the live example I just added.

Comment: why so complicated and not using DOM-methods like children for that?

Comment: @Christoph: The above is not complicated, and it *does* use the DOM. `firstChild`, `nextSibling`, `nodeName`, they're all basic DOM stuff. Using `children` wouldn't simplify the above -- complicate it if anything.

Answer (score 1):

By pure javascript, you can try:

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('#image-container img');
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    console.log(arr[i].getAttribute('src'))
}
```

On browsers that support querySelectorAll. (IE8 and up, modern versions of others, not IE7 and down.) - As mentioned in the comment by T.J. Crowder

Comment: On browsers that support `querySelectorAll`. (IE8 and up, modern versions of others, not IE7 and down.) Also, you're grabbing the `src` attribute. The sample array doesn't have that, it has the `id` values.